# Angular2 REST API

Tags: rest, http, angular, get

I learn Angular2 and now i try to get my data from a rest service. My rest service works and i can get data from there.

But angular always give my this error message: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

This is my Service:

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { Person } from '../_models/person';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class PersonService {
    private headers: Headers;

    constructor(private http: Http)
    {
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    }

    getPersons(): Observable<Person[]> {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:54612/api/Person')
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: Response | any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

This is the component for the view:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from '../_models/person';
import { PersonService } from '../_services/person.service';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
    providers: [ PersonService ]
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    errorMessage: string;
    personen: Person[] = [];

    constructor(private personService: PersonService) { }

    ngOnInit() { this.getPersons(); }

    getPersons() {
        this.personService.getPersons()
            .subscribe(
            personen => this.personen = personen,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

And this is my view:

```
<h1>Tour of Heroes</h1>
<h3>Heroes:</h3>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let person of personen">{{person.IDPerson}}</li>
</ul>
<p class="error" *ngIf="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</p>
```

Comment: Did you try logging the returned json/parsed json to see what the data looks like? Maybe the issue is with your api running on `localhost:54612`

Comment: I got this from the api: <ArrayOfPerson xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CarWarsRest.Models"><Person><Adresse i:nil="true" /><EMail i:nil="true" /><Geburtsdatum>0001-01-01T00:00:00</Geburtsdatum><IDPerson>1</IDPerson><Land i:nil="true" /><Mobile i:nil="true" /><Name i:nil="true" /><Ort i:nil="true" /><PLZ>0</PLZ><Passwort i:nil="true" /><Registrationsdatum>0001-01-01T00:00:00</Registrationsdatum><Telefon i:nil="true" /><Vorname i:nil="true" /></Person></ArrayOfPerson>. Is this what you mean?

Comment: This is not JSON. json starts with `{`and has key values such as `"key":"value"` then it finishes with `}` I guess this is why you cannot parse the json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server is return XML. The reason is probably because it's the default when you don't explicitly set the Accept to something else. You have set it in the `Headers` to JSON, but you never add the headers to the request. You need to do

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:54612/api/Person', { headers: this.headers });
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I just had to set my headers. What a facepalm :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet, in your getPersons()

```
return this.http.get('http://localhost:54612/api/Person',{headers: this.headers })
        .map((response:Response) => response.json())
```